# microk8s join node has no effect

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I did command om master node

```
microk8s add-node
From the node you wish to join to this cluster, run the following:
microk8s join 192.168.0.xxx:25000/token

If the node you are adding is not reachable through the default interface you can use one of the following:
 microk8s join 192.168.0.yyy:25000/token
 microk8s join 192.168.0.xxx:25000/token
 microk8s join 172.17.0.1:25000/token
```

and on another machine i did

```
microk8s join 192.168.0.xxx:25000/token
Contacting cluster at 192.168.0.xxx
Waiting for this node to finish joining the cluster. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..
```

it ended without messages but on master node command output `microk8s.kubectl get no` doesn'show this node only default node

Comment: Please execute command microk8s status and  microk8s inspect for a deeper inspection. Did you turn on firewall (ufw)? If yes, consider allowing all node ips like:  
ufw allow from [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx](https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/) (repeat for all nodes including the current node)? Did your instances  instances having both an internal and public network ? Sometimes they would try talking to the wrong ones. When you will take away the external interfaces, it will work properly.

Comment: For now i downgrade microk8s to 1.18 and there node joined and exists in node list.

Answer (score 4):

Solution may be  as @Sultan Zhumatayev said downgrading [microk8s](https://microk8s.io/) to `1.18` and node will join and appear in node list.

However firstly to check where problem lies you can execute commands: `$ microk8s status` and `$ microk8s inspect` for a deeper inspection

Another possible solutions:

**1.** If you turn on firewall (ufw), consider allowing all node ips like: ufw allow from  `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`  (repeat for all nodes including the current node).  If your instances instances having both an internal and public network, they could try talking to the wrong ones. After taking away the external interfaces, it will work properly.  Take a look: [microk8s-join-stuck](https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/j2pe17/microk8s_join_failing_how_to_troubleshoot/).

**2.** Try to disconnect the node from the cluster. Run on the node the following command:

```
$ sudo microk8s leave
```

Then you can try to connect it again, by running add-node on the master:

```
$ sudo microk8s add-node
```

and then the respective command on the node again:

```
$ sudo microk8s join
```

Read more: [microk8s-join](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/1401).

See also: [microk8s](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/11/26/running-kubernetes-locally-on-linux-with-microk8s/).

Comment: No because I did inspection and there was one warning about iptables  then i did fix it,but node didn't join,I tried leave and it was endless did add node many times with different urls had no effect .Only downgrade helped.

Comment: I have mentioned your solution as possible solution but for such problems points 1/2 can also help. I have also given hints for community how to debug and find the cause of problem (proper commands).

Comment: Searched all over GitHub and Stackoverflow, this is the best answer. Specifically running `sudo ufw allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Answer (score 1):

I was also having some trouble listing the microk8s nodes and what worked for me was giving an unique hostname of each of the pies in the `/etc/hostname` file (the default hostname in all the pies after installation was ubuntu). After I rebooted each of the nodes, they showed up with the `microk8s kubectl get no` on the master node.

It seems that microk8s uses the hostname as an identifier for a the nodes, or at list the `kubectl get node`, instead of their ip, which in my case, I would prefer. At least in my case I'm using statics ips in my local network.

Comment: Can confirm, i have a cluster of 3 Raspberry Pi 4 Bs. With a fresh Ubuntu install they all used the hostname `ubuntu`, so I used `sudo hostnamectl set-hostname <unique hostname>` on every Pi and gave them unique hostnames instead. Now all nodes show up in `kubectl get nodes`.