# Microk8s joining cluster failed. Could not verify the identity of

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, virtual-machine, virtualbox, microk8s

I am trying to learn microk8s. I installed 3 Ubuntu in my virtual box. I installed the microk8s on each of these virtual machines. I want machines in the form of master node and 2 worker nodes to communicate with each other.

I tried to use this command in first machine:

```
microk8s add-node
```

And in the second machine, I tried to join this as a worker. But it does not work. I gave this error:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in the latest master, and the fix is working on being backported to all supported versions (1.21, 1.22, 1.23). Check for latest version.

You can try the following:

On the existing cluster node. restarting the service might not be needed

```
sudo snap restart microk8s.daemon-cluster-agent

micro k8s add-node
```

This will give you a new join URL. You should then be able to use that to join your second node to the cluster.

Here is the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/canonical/microk8s/issues/2420) you can refer to for more information.

Comment: first of all, thank you for your answer. I tried this solution and it did not work.

Comment: did you check this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61305498/kubernetes-couldnt-able-to-join-master-node-error-execution-phase-preflight).

Comment: I have to use microk8s.  Must I install kubernetes? Why? I just installed microk8s.

Comment: I use different machines. But, both of them have same version of ubuntu

Comment: As per my knowledge if we have kubernetes it will be more efficient. Try to [install kubernetes with microk8s](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-a-local-kubernetes-with-microk8s#1-overview).

Comment: meanwhile check if this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66463049/microk8s-join-node-has-no-effect) If you find any information.

Comment: I turned off firewall

Comment: Try using kubernetes

Comment: I have to use microk8s :)